# How to fetch data from api when new data is added to it using UseEffect React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a chat app, the issue that i'm facing is the following:

When i open the chat the useEffect render the function to fetch all the message inside that particular chat and return it to me, but if i add a new message on that particular chat the hooks is not updated and do not show the new message

Here is the code

```
const ChatWindow = () => {

    const [loadMessage, setLoadMessage] = useState([])
    const [message, setMessage] = useState({
        message: ""
    })
    

    useEffect(() => {
        loadMessageInChat() 
    },[]); 
    

    //Api call to load message

    const loadMessageInChat = async() => {
        try {
           const attempt = await axios.get(`https://bbobras.onrender.com/api/messages/${openWindow.chatInfo._id}`,config)
            if(attempt.status === 200){ 
//This will return an [{}]
                setLoadMessage(attempt.data.data)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } 
    }  
}

export default ChatWindow;
```

I know that passing an empty array on useEffect will only call loadMessageInChat() once, so i thought to pass the hook loadMessage into it, but doing that will create an infinite loop and fetch the data over and over again because what i get from the api is an [{}] so if i'm not wrong i understand this behaviour as {} === {} --> False and that's why the infinite loop.

Sorry but i'm so junior in react and i'm trying to solve this but i can't get any solution.

Thanks!